# C# Event Passing/Bubble Up

Tags: c#, .net, events

I subscribe to an `Event` inside a `class`.  Such as

```
MainStation mainStation = StationFactory.GetMainStation();  
mainStation.FrequencyChanged += new EventArgs(MainStation_FrequencyChanged);
```

My `MainStation` class raises the event on some condition by just calling the event `FrequencyChanged()`

**The Problem**

Now I have a scenario where I **must** instantiate `SubStation` from `MainStation` which is also a subclass of `MainStation` with some additional features and `FrequencyChanged` event must be subscribed as the `MainStation` subscrbed. Consider the code noted below:

```
public class MainStation
{
    public event EventHandler FrequencyChanged;
    public static SubStation CreateSubStation()
    {
        SubStation subStation = new SubStation();
        //here I want to pass/bubble FrequencyChanged event to SubStation
        subStation.FrequencyChanged = FrequencyChanged; //THIS IS WRONG
    }
}
```

**Bottom Line**
I want to fire an event that a class subscribes from another class, also bubble up events

**Update**
`StationFactory` creates `MainStation` and the `FrequencyChanged` event in `MainStation` instance is set as defined in the first code block.

Comment: Just wondering why this is in CW. Seems like a good question with a definitive answer. Just curious...   ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `FrequencyChanged` does not belong to `MainStation`, but rather to some `Base`, you're going to have to chain and expose the event you're interested in.

```
public class MainStation : Base
{
    public event EventHandler StationFrequencyChanged;

    public MainStation()
    {
        // ...

        this.FrequencyChanged += new EventHandler(MainStation_FrequencyChanged);
    }

    void MainStation_FrequencyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (StationFrequencyChanged != null)
            StationFrequencyChanged(sender, e);
    }

    public void GetEventsFrom(MainStation src)
    {
        //this is where you assign src events to your object
        this.StationFrequencyChanged = src.StationFrequencyChanged;
    }

    public static SubStation CreateSubStation(MainStation main)
    {
        SubStation subStation = new SubStation();

        //register events    
        subStation.GetEventsFrom(main);

        return subStation;
    } 
}

public class SubStation : MainStation
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks Dynami for your reply! Seems like this is what I wanted. I cannot test the code right now cuz I am on the move. I will test it as soon as possbile and let you know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you need something more flexible, it is possible to use WPF RoutedEvents.

Or implement similar approach manually: organize objects into tree and write an event manager that can route events upwards from tree node. If tree hierarchy fits your needs, it will be more convenient and predictable than forwarding every individual event in handler.

Answer (score 0):

If your CreateSubStation method were not static, then the code you have would work as expected.  (Provided that the event handlers on MainStation were setup before you created Substation...which isn't really a great design, IMO.)